# How to display images from a nested json array in each div using javascript jquery(Duplicate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi guys Im having trouble in displaying images from a nested array because its displaying all images in one div container instead of 1 div 1 images
I dont know now what should I do?
Im sorry for my bad English anyway here is my codes

**Update**
I have included the div for map marker and the container for results in which the product/s corresponding wit the marker will be displayed on the search container

**HTML**

```
//For Marker
<div class='e-mapMarker'></div>

//For Search Result Container

<div id='search-result'>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function displayData(e)
{
var html = '';
var html2 = '';
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
    dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key, item,
    mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
var collection = [];
collection = collection.concat(flsSites, flsInstallation, flsProduct);

var sites = $('#fls_site').attr('data-flag');
var installation = $('#fls_installation').attr('data-flag');
var product = $('#fls_products').attr('data-flag');

for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {

    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i]) {
        index = i;
    }

}

html += '<div id="infocontainer" class="map_element">';
html += "<div class='p-image'><img src='src/images/" + collection[index].company_logo + "' /></div>";
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + collection[index].site_name + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + collection[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + collection[index].country_name + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';

html2 += '<div class="rightcontainer">';
html2 += collection[index].products.map(product => "<div class='p-name'><img src='src/images/" + product.image + "' /><br></div>");
html2 += '<div id="imagedetail">';
html2 += '<span class="details">' + collection[index].products[0].pump +'</span>';
html2 += '</div>';
html2 += '</div>';
if (!document.getElementById('map_tooltip'))
{
    tooltipdiv = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "map_tooltip");
    $(document.body).append(tooltipdiv);
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "display": "none", "padding": "5px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "13000",
        "cursor": "default",
        "font-family": "Segoe UI",
        "color": "#707070",
        "font-size": "12px", "pointer-events": "none",
        "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
        "border": "1px solid #707070"
    });
}
else
{
    tooltipdiv = $("#map_tooltip");
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "left": (e.pageX + 5),
        "top": (e.pageY + 5)
    });
    $(tooltipdiv).html(html).show("slow");
    $('#search-result').append(html2);
}

}
```

And this is what I got

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it's better to paste your complete code on jsfiddle. It would be easy for people to help you.

Comment: @Chen-TaiHou I have tried pasting my code in jsfiddle in some of my question and have a hard time with jsfiddle :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your create and append your div's outside of the for loop, which means that it will only be executed once. Move the code inside the loop.

Comment: it still the  same result two images inside one div I need div one contains image 1 the on the bottom of div one will be div two and on the div two contains image two